# Deploying Castle Monorail on Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, castle-monorail

I'm deploying a castle monorail web application to Windows Server 2003.
I've already set the httphandler mapping in web.config as follows :

```
<httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" path="*.castle" type="Castle.MonoRail.Framework.MonoRailHttpHandlerFactory, Castle.MonoRail.Framework" />
</httpHandlers>

<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="castle page" path="*.castle" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

But whenever I tried to access http://localhost/app/Home/Index.castle the web server always returns HTTP 404 Not Found. It looks like the mapping is not handled by ASP.NET engine, like I've been missing a step or two in the configuration. Any solution?

Comment: did you follow the instructions in http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/trunk/usersguide/installing.html ?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer I did follow the instructions. But I don't think I read anything about doing IISReset, and as it turns out, a simple iisreset solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using IIS 6.0 the `<system.webServer>` section is ignored and you need to associate the `.castle` extension with the ASP.NET ISAPI filter in the IIS control panel.

Phil Haack [blogged about](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) how to achieve this with ASP.NET MVC and the `.mvc` extension. For you this would be the .castle extension:

[image]